# Wordpress nested shortcodes of same type

Tags: wordpress

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes - as you can read here shortcodes like:

```
[tag-a]
   [tag-a]
   [/tag-a]
[/tag-a]
```

Will not work. And I dont see any explaination about it. So my question is how to make, and is it possible - to create nested shortcodes of the same type in wordpress?

Comment: `This is a limitation of the context-free regexp parser used by do_shortcode() - it is very fast but does not count levels of nesting, so it can't match each opening tag with its correct closing tag in these cases.`

Answer (score 0):

You can create different aliases for the same shorcode

```
add_shortcode('tag','my_shortcode_function');
add_shortcode('sub-tag','my_shortcode_function');
function my_shortcode_function($atts,$content) {
    // do things here
}
```

And then use it like this

```
[tag]
  [sub-tag]
  [/sub-tag]
[/tag]
```

They will do the same thing, but the parser will know how to close them.